# unknown timedelta / datetime format

Tags: python, sql-server, datetime

I'm working with a legacy database (SQL-Server 2008) and I extracted some data as follows :

I'm totally lost with what the StartTime and EndTime format is ? I'm pretty sure I'm googling the wrong thing but I'm not sure what to google either!

I've tried to convert to a timedelta or pandas datetime object using the standard `pd_to_datetime` or `pd_to_timedelta` but it's not anything I can make sense off.

the 3rd row gives me `1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000540`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s+')
print(df)

StartDate   StartTime   EndTime Duration
0   18/11/2006  NaN NaN 0
1   23/12/2006  NaN NaN 0
2   23/12/2006  540.0   1080.0  540
3   23/12/2006  540.0   1020.0  480
4   23/12/2006  540.0   1020.0  480
5   30/12/2006  630.0   1080.0  450
6   30/12/2006  540.0   1020.0  480
7   30/12/2006  540.0   1020.0  480
8   30/12/2006  540.0   1020.0  480
9   30/12/2006  540.0   1020.0  480
10  06/01/2007  1020.0  1200.0  180
11  06/01/2007  540.0   1020.0  480
12  06/01/2007  540.0   1020.0  480
13  06/01/2007  1020.0  1200.0  180
14  06/01/2007  1020.0  1200.0  180
15  18/11/2006  540.0   780.0   240
16  18/11/2006  900.0   960.0   60
17  23/12/2006  NaN NaN 0
18  23/12/2006  540.0   1080.0  540
19  23/12/2006  540.0   1020.0  480
20  23/12/2006  540.0   1020.0  480
21  23/12/2006  540.0   1020.0  480
22  09/09/2006  540.0   1050.0  510
23  09/09/2006  540.0   1050.0  510
24  09/09/2006  540.0   1020.0  480
```

is anyone able to help ?

Comment: Could StartTime and EndTime be the minutes since midnight on StartDate?

Comment: @Isaac just figured it out, they are seconds, passing `unit=s` into the `to_datetime` sorts it out.

Comment: `datetime` has no format, it's a binary value. To read data from any database use `read_sql`, not `read_clipboard`. What you posted looks like dates and decimals displayed with the wrong layout. `read_sql` wouldn't have any issues, it would return the values in different columns

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Of course, I wrote that in to aid anyone that wanted to copy the data in, I'm reading in a massive table of 44million rows, I don't think copy & paste can handle that. What I posted above is from `read_sql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have endured a bit longer before posting a question,

for the lost people that might have the same question - the number was the time in seconds, passing in a unit argument to the `to_datetime` function chained with a `dt.strftime()` gives me the data, which seems about right :

as I'm not really sure what's happening under the hood, I'm happy to accept an answer from anyone who can give a small explanation of what's been executed behind the scenes.

```
df['StartTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartTime'],unit='s').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df['EndTime']= pd.to_datetime(df['EndTime'],unit='s').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df['Duration'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Duration'],unit='s').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

print(df)

StartDate   StartTime   EndTime Duration
0   18/11/2006  NaT NaT 00:00:00
1   23/12/2006  NaT NaT 00:00:00
2   23/12/2006  00:09:00    00:18:00    00:09:00
3   23/12/2006  00:09:00    00:17:00    00:08:00
4   23/12/2006  00:09:00    00:17:00    00:08:00
5   30/12/2006  00:10:30    00:18:00    00:07:30
6   30/12/2006  00:09:00    00:17:00    00:08:00
7   30/12/2006  00:09:00    00:17:00    00:08:00
8   30/12/2006  00:09:00    00:17:00    00:08:00
9   30/12/2006  00:09:00    00:17:00    00:08:00
10  06/01/2007  00:17:00    00:20:00    00:03:00
11  06/01/2007  00:09:00    00:17:00    00:08:00
12  06/01/2007  00:09:00    00:17:00    00:08:00
13  06/01/2007  00:17:00    00:20:00    00:03:00
14  06/01/2007  00:17:00    00:20:00    00:03:00
15  18/11/2006  00:09:00    00:13:00    00:04:00
16  18/11/2006  00:15:00    00:16:00    00:01:00
17  23/12/2006  NaT NaT 00:00:00
18  23/12/2006  00:09:00    00:18:00    00:09:00
19  23/12/2006  00:09:00    00:17:00    00:08:00
20  23/12/2006  00:09:00    00:17:00    00:08:00
21  23/12/2006  00:09:00    00:17:00    00:08:00
22  09/09/2006  00:09:00    00:17:30    00:08:30
23  09/09/2006  00:09:00    00:17:30    00:08:30
24  09/09/2006  00:09:00    00:17:00    00:08:00
```